# MATLAB, I have two tables in Matlab, can do apply outer join on these two tables?

Tags: matlab-table

I am using matlab. I have two tables (by using readtable), now, I would like to out join these two tables. Can I do that in Matlab? If yes, how?

Say, I have a table called patients: load patients;

patients table: Gender Age Smoker BloodPressure ______ ___ ______ _______________

Smith       Male      38     true      124          93
Johnson     Male      43     false     109          77

Then, I have a table of address (name, address). Some people have 2 or more addresses in the address table, and I want to have a table that lists every row in the patients and all the addresses for them.

address table:

```
           Address
           --------
```

Smith     1234 ABC street
Smith     4567 DEF street

I want to create a new table, pa, such that it has 3 rows:

```
     Gender    Age    Smoker     BloodPressure       Address
        ______    ___    ______    _______________   --------
```

Smith       Male      38     true      124          93   1234 ABC street
Smith       Male      38     true      124          93   4567 DEF street
Johnson     Male      43     false     109          77

How to create that in Matlab code?

Thanks a lot!

Jennifer

Comment: Could you provide example code, this will help everyone else to provide you a good answer.

Comment: Well, when I googled "matlab outer join", literally the first link was http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try and will report back.

Comment: I think that link is the right link to my question!.

Comment: But, what if I don't have a key in the two tables. I want every combination of the rows. Say, table A has 10 rows; B has 5 rows, the new table C = [A, B] should have 50 rows.